# Accessing the Debug LEDs on Dell OptiPlexes

Tags: ubuntu, debug, acpi, led, dell-optiplex

Dell OptiPlex machines have debug LEDs on the front panel that say 1-2-3-4. 
How can they be accessed from Linux/Ubuntu? 
Perhaps via ACPI commands?

Comment: Can't tell for Dell, but on my thinkpad I can act on LEDs by writing to `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness`, for instance `echo 3 >/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness`. You may have a similiar capability in your Dell.

Comment: nope nothing there